# In my project I wrote with Angular, I get a 'Cannot Get' error when I run it

Tags: angular, get

There was no problem in the project before. This problem occurred suddenly.

I get a 'Cannot Get' error when I say run after every encoding process. Then, when I come to the project and make such a change in any html and any component.ts files and save both, the project works fine. [***Change made: to leave a space in any empty space in ts and html files with a space key.***]

How can I solve this ??
Where should I check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved.
If you experience such a problem, you can run the ng build code to see and fix which components you received errors.
:) it was a very simple mistake. We have gained experience :))**